# How to start dart web app on server on default port

Tags: dart

I just install dart on my server Ubuntu 12.04. I started on mydomain.com:8080/ and "hello word" displayed. But for real web app I need to run on address mydomain.com (without :8080). When I try to set port 80 on dart script it failed because apache already run on port 80. Here is my current dart script: https://www.dartlang.org/dart-by-example/#http-server So how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your Dart app to bind to port 80 you have to stop Apache or bind Apache to another port.
Another solution is to make Dart run by Apache http://news.dartlang.org/2012/05/run-dart-in-apache-web-server.html (didn't read or try myself)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Apache as a proxy (via mod_proxy) to your Dart based webserver. It allows you to have both the power of Apache and Dart on the same device. I haven't used this approach in combination with Dart yet, but I use it with Java applications on Tomcat. [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Using+Apache+with+mod_proxy) is a simple Tomcat related example (scroll down to "Configure mod_proxy"). It should be easy to apply that to a Dart based server.

But that might not work with Websockets. The good thing about Websockets is that they aren't limited by the same origin policy, so you can run your Websocket applications on another port.